# Javascript - Conditional using the domain name

Tags: javascript

I have solve a solution that make conditional to know if I'm NOT in the index page, the background image of an element should be none. How can I do this without need to write the page domain? 
A solution better than this:

```
if(window.location.href != 'http://example.com/'){
  document.querySelector('.menu-principal')
  .style.backgroundImage = 'none' 
}
```

I'm only want to know if I'm in the index page or Not, without need to write the page domain.

Comment: Yes, there would be two `//` before `mysite`

Comment: Use a string replacement to replace your scheme://domain.tld/ with "" then you will only have your resource path left.

Comment: Ignore this fact that i'm using '/' or '//' it isn't the issue root. The SO blocked my post when I wrote '//' in the domain

Comment: It was blocking the `mysite.com` part of it, just change to `example.com` and it will be accepted (hope that's OK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to check `location.pathname`, which will hold everything in the URL string past the domain - for example, for this page, whose URL is

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000339/javascript-conditional-using-the-domain-name/53000364
```

the pathname is

```
/questions/53000339/javascript-conditional-using-the-domain-name/53000364
```

When on an index page, even when there's no trailing `/` in the URL string, the pathname is `/`. So, if your pathname is anything other than `/`, you know that you're on somewhere other than the index page:

```
if (window.location.pathname !== '/'){
  document.querySelector('.menu-principal')
    .style.backgroundImage = 'none' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var { pathname } = window.location;

if (!(pathname == "" || pathname == "/" || pathname == "/index.html")) {
    document.querySelector(".menu-principal").style.backgroundImage = "none";
}
```

So the following would all be the index page, and therefore the background image would be visible:

```
https://stackoverflow.com
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://stackoverflow.com/index.html
```